# Atom Editor unintentional Euro symbol

Tags: atom-editor

when I am coding in atom editor,
pressing the 'E' button produces a '€' symbol on the screen.
This seems to happen at random times, but once it did, it proceeds to happen until I close the editor an reopen it.
Not only that, but pressing '2' or '3' produces '²' or '³', respectively.
The phenomenon looks like a permanent pressing of the 'Alt Gr' button on a German keyboard, which I am using.
Does anybody have any idea what might me the reason for this weird anormality?
I use atom version 1.7.4 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the package "keyboard-localization"? It might solve your problems.

https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization